# Printing mongoose collections in jade template; only getting one document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I’m new to web development in general and wonder why the the *cursor* method for mongoose only returns the first document in the collection and not all of them?

My goal is to pass these documents to a jade template.

I'm using MongoDB and Express

The code:

```
var array = [];
var stream = MyModel.find({}).cursor();

stream.on('data',function(task){
    array.push(task)
});

stream.on('error', function(err){
    //Handle error
});

stream.on('close', function(){
res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Dashboard', csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), array: array});
});
```

Since I'm new to this my "code-jargon" might not be spot on so i'll be happy to specify if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
MyModel.find({},function(err,docs){
 res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Dashboard', csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), array: docs});
});
```

according to mongoose doc, you can attach a callback to the query, so it will turn the cursor into an array of documents.